# Push segue is messing with constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a push segue going from my home `UIViewController` to a `UITabBarController`. I need to use a push segue because I require a navigation bar at the top and I can't embed a `UITabBarController` in a Navigation Controller.

When I preform the initial segue, it goes to the `UITabBarController` and then creates a small margin underneath the navigation bar and above my content. When I switch tabs, this padding is removed, even when I switch back to the initial tab. Then, when I use the Push Segue's back button, my root view controller looses some constraints: I have a collectionView here that pushes up underneath some buttons on the page. 
[image: Description of problem]

There used to be a weird shift with the buttons, and then now they don't move because I fixed the constraints. However, the constraints on the `CollectionView` seem good.

[image: constraints]

It almost seems more like it could be that the items inside the CollectionView are shifting up, not the CollectionView itself. Is this possible? Could I fix this?

This does not happen when I switch to a Modal segue instead of a push.
Any suggestions on how I might fix this strange problem? Or can someone suggest a good way to get a Modal segue working for my TabViewController?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by modifying  Lord Zsolt's answer here.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

if (self.searchBar.frame.origin.y == 20) {
    [self.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.searchBar.frame.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
    [self.ptasksTable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.ptasksTable.frame.size.width, self.ptasksTable.frame.size.height+20)];
     }
}
```

I'm checking if the origin of the first item on my view is `y=20`, and if so, setting the y origin to 0 and increasing the size of the `TableView` below by 20 to fill the space.